# How to split a string in Java?

Tags: java, string

I have a group of radio buttons and a group of checkboxes. I want to print out the selected radio buttons/checked boxes. To print out the radio button selected I use

```
Object table = radio.getValue();
System.out.println(table);
```

I get the radio button selected. To get which checkboxes have been selected I use the same:

```
Object columns = check.getValue();
System.out.println(columns);
```

I get the checkboxes which have been checked but with square brackets surrounding them, e.g
if I check the boxes

> columnA, columnC, columnF

the printed line would look like this:

> [columnA, columnC, columnF]

I want to put the strings of the selected checkboxes into my sql query so I have something like this `data.executeQuery("Select " + columns + " From " + table);`

It works with the `table` but it doesn't work with the `columns`.

Comment: I started to edit this mess but realized I did not know what a `ratio` button is.  DYM `JRadioButton`?  Also do you want to **spit** a `String` or **split** it?  For future posts, you may want to review them more carefully, since that question reads like nonsense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this paricular application, you do not need to split a string. You may use

```
String str = columns.toString(); // "[colummA, colummC, colummF]"
System.out.println(str.substring(1, str.length() - 1));
```

You may also form a comma-separated string using

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(Object obj : columns) {
    if (sb.length() != 0) sb.append(",");
    sb.append(obj);
}
```

However, to answer the question:

String is splitted via `split(String)` method using a [Regular Expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) syntax. As you have a list of items, converting it to a `String` and splitting it isnt an effective decision.

Answer (score 1):

columns is an array containing all values of the selected checkboxes. Make sure that the default toString method outputs the items separated by a ","

Answer (score 1):

this is because default

```
  check.getValue().toString()
```

called and depending on if its a List or a HashSet and default toString() method of List/HashSet is called which by default appends [] while printing the values so  for your case you could either use a collection with a overridden toString() method as per your requirement or just write you custom toString method and call it instead of the default toString Method

here is a sample implementation if it is HashSet

```
  private String getHashSetString(Set<String> myset){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Iterator<String> i = myset.iterator();
    if (! i.hasNext())
        return "";
    for (;;) {
        Long e = i.next();
        sb.append(e);
        if (! i.hasNext())
        return sb.toString();
        sb.append(",");
    }
}
```

So instead of

```
  data.executeQuery("Select " + columns + " From " + table);
```

write

```
  data.executeQuery("Select " + columns.getHashSetString() + " From " + table);
```